# Cannot send headers; headers already sent When integrate third party API in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api, integration, http-header

I am integrating third party API (wordpress) in magento on observer.

Integration working fine on my local system, but when I deploy it on server it give me error like below:

```
Cannot send headers; headers already sent

2020-07-22T08:58:58+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Zend_Controller_Response_Exception' with message 'Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /var/www/html/app/code/local/Custom/Wordpressapi/Model/Observer.php, line 182' in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:344
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(148): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
#1 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php(107): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setRedirect('*/*/', 302)
#2 /var/www/html/app/code/local/Custom/Wordpressapi/Model/Observer.php(277): Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http->setRedirect('*/*/')
#3 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Custom_Wordpressapi_Model_Observer->postProductAsBlog(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#4 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Sterling_Blogapi_Model_Observer), 'postProductAsBl...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#5 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(483): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalog_product...', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(466): Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product...', Array)
#7 /var/www/html/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php(549): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_afterSave()
#8 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->_afterSave()
#9 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(554): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#10 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->saveAction()
#11 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#12 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(719): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /var/www/html/index.php(94): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Here is the code snippet from my observer file:

```
<?php
class Custom_Wordpressapi_Model_Observer
{
    const WORDPRESS_BLOG_API_URL = "wordpresapi/api/api_url";
    const WORDPRESS_BLOG_USERNAME = "wordpresapi/api/username";
    const WORDPRESS_BLOG_PASSWORD = "wordpresapi/api/password";

   
    public function postProductAsBlog(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if(Mage::registry('catalog_product_save_after_observer_executed')){
            return $this; //this method has already been executed once in this request
        }
        Mage::register('catalog_product_save_after_observer_executed',true);

        if(!Mage::helper('custom_wordpressapi')->isEnable())
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError("Blog api module is disabled, So not able to create/update post on Blog site."); 
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect('*/*/')->sendResponse();
            return;
        }

        $apiUrl = trim(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::WORDPRESS_BLOG_API_URL));
        $username = trim(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::WORDPRESS_BLOG_USERNAME));
        $password = Mage::helper('core')->decrypt(trim(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::WORDPRESS_BLOG_PASSWORD)));

        if($apiUrl == '' && $username == '' && $password == '')
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError("Blog api config information missing, So not able to create/update post on Blog site."); 
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect('*/*/')->sendResponse();
            return;
        }

        /*if(Mage::registry('catalog_product_save_after_observer_executed')){
            return $this; //this method has already been executed once in this request
        }*/

        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $authorization = "Authorization: Basic $username:$password";

        $post_id =  $id = $name = $title = $conditionType = $condition = $machineUrl = $imgUrl = $capacity = $sku = $shortDesc = $otherInfo = $postContent = $price ='';
        $postResponse  = $metaInfo = $categories = array();
        $updateImage = false;
     
        $attributeSetModel = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set");
        $attributeSetModel->load($product->getAttributeSetId());
        $attributeSetName  = $attributeSetModel->getAttributeSetName();


        if((!empty($product) && $product->getIsOption() != 1) && $product->getPostToApi() == 1 && ($product->getStatus() == 1 && $product->getIsInStock() == 1) && $attributeSetName == 'Default' )
        {
            $sku = trim($product->getSku());
            $shortDesc = strtoupper(trim($product->getShortDescription()));
            $name = trim($product->getName());
            $machineUrl = trim(Mage::getBaseUrl().$product->getUrlPath());
            $imgUrl =(string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(500);
            $capacity = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('capacity')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
            $condition =  trim($product->getCondition());


            if($product->getUpdateImage() == 1)
            {
                $updateImage = true;
            }else{
                $updateImage = false;
            }
            if(trim(strtolower($condition)) == '812')
            {
                $conditionType = ' New';
            }
            else
            {
                if(trim(strtolower($condition)) == '814')
                { $conditionType = ' Used'; }
                else {$conditionType = '';}
            }

            $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
            foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
                $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
                $categories[] = $_cat->getName();
            }
            $metaTitle = trim($product->getMetaTitle());
            $metaKeywords = trim($product->getMetaKeyword());
            $metaDesc = trim($product->getMetaDescription());
            $metaInfo = array('title' =>$metaTitle,'keywords'=>$metaKeywords,'description'=>$metaDesc);

            $title = strtoupper(trim($capacity.$conditionType." ".$name." #".$sku));

            if(!empty($shortDesc))
            {
                $postContent .= '<p>'.$shortDesc.'</p>';
            }

            if($product->getPrice() > 0 && $product->getPrice() != '')
            {
                $price = Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getPrice(), true, false);
            }
            else
            {
                $price = "Call for price";
            }

            if($price != '')
            {
                $postContent .= '<p> Cost: '.$price.'</p>';
            }

            if(!empty($machineUrl))
            {
                $postContent .= '<p><a href="'.$machineUrl.'" title="Machine Url">'.$machineUrl.'</a></p>';
            }

            $postDatas = array(
                'title' => $title,
                'categories' => $categories,
                'machine_url' => $machineUrl,
                'short_description' => $shortDesc,
                'image_url' => $imgUrl,
                'other_info' => $otherInfo,
                'blog_post_content' => $postContent,
                'meta_info'=>$metaInfo
            );

            if(Mage::registry('catalog_product_saved_status') == 'old'){
                $modelInfo = Mage::getModel('wordpresapi/wordpresapi')->getCollection();

                $modelInfo->addFieldToSelect(array('id','blog_id'))->addFieldToFilter('product_sku',array('eq'=>$sku));

                $modelData = $modelInfo->getData();

                if($modelInfo->count() > 0)
                {
                    $postDatas['post_id'] = $post_id = $modelData[0]['blog_id'];
                    $postDatas['update_image']= $updateImage;
                    $id = $modelData[0]['id'];
                }

            }

            try {
                $url = $apiUrl;

                $curl = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl();

                $curl->setConfig(array('timeout' => 0));
                $headers= array('Content-Type: application/json',$authorization);

                $curl->write(Zend_Http_Client::POST, $url, '1.0', $headers, json_encode($postDatas));
                $res = $curl->read();
                $response = '';

                $httpCode = Zend_Http_Response::extractCode($res);
                $response = Zend_Http_Response::extractBody($res);
                $curl->close();


                if ($httpCode == 200) //if success
                {
               $response = json_decode($response);

                    if (!empty($response) && is_object($response))
                    {

                        if (property_exists($response,'code') && $response->code == 'post_created' || $response->code == 'post_updated') {
                            if(!empty($response->data) && $response->data != null){ 
                                $saveResponse = array();
                                $product_sku = $blog_id = '';
                                $update_data = false;
                                $dataRes = $response->data;

                                foreach ($dataRes as $k => $data) {

                                    if($k == 'id')
                                    {
                                        $blog_id = $data;
                                    }
                                    if($k == 'date_gmt')
                                    {
                                        $saveResponse['date_created_gmt'] = $data;
                                    }
                                    if($k == 'link')
                                    {
                                        $saveResponse['post_link'] = $data;
                                    }
                                    if($k == 'modified_gmt')
                                    {
                                        $saveResponse['date_updated_gmt'] = $data;
                                    }
                                    if($k == 'categories')
                                    {
                                        $saveResponse['categories'] = (array)$data;
                                    }
                                    $product_sku = $sku;
                                    $update_data = true;
                                }


                                if($update_data == true)
                                {
                                    $infoSet = array('blog_id'=>$blog_id,'product_sku'=>$product_sku,'additional_info'=>null,'other_info'=>serialize($saveResponse));
                                    if($post_id == '')
                                        $model = Mage::getModel('wordpresapi/wordpresapi')->setData($infoSet);
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $infoSet['id'] = $id;
                                        $model = Mage::getModel('wordpresapi/wordpresapi')->load($id);
                                        $model->setData($infoSet);
                                    }
                                    $model->save();
                                }
                            }
                            Mage::log("Success API Msg -- ".$response->message.". For product sku $sku", null, 'blog-api.log', true);
                            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess("Blog Post API 0 : ".$response->message); 


                        }
                       else{
                           Mage::log("API Msg -- ".$response->message.". For product sku $sku", null, 'blog-api.log', true);
                           Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError("Blog Post API 1 : ".$response->message); 

                       }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError("Blog Post API, Nothing to post. : ".$response->message); 
                    }

                }
                
            }catch (Exception $e)
            {
                Mage::log("Error API Msg -- " . $e->getMessage().". For product sku $sku", null, 'blog-api.log', true);
            }

            Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect('*/*/')->sendResponse();

        }
        else{
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect('*/*/')->sendResponse();
        }
        return;
    }


    public function postProductData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if(Mage::helper('custom_wordpressapi')->isModuleEnabled()) {
            $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
            Mage::unregister('catalog_product_saved_status');

            if ($product->isObjectNew()) {
                Mage::register('catalog_product_saved_status', "new");
            } else {
                Mage::register('catalog_product_saved_status', "old");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this normally happens due to white space or if you have php closing bracket at last line just remove it you dont need it.

Comment: @Chikku, both of these thing are not in my case

Comment: @Chikku, I have updated the question with exception log

Comment: @Chikku, Is this due to redirect statement?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed if this is not your case then you can use ob_start for output buffering

```
<?php
  ob_start();

  // code 

 ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Its not working

Comment: You have to add this  to the page that triggered the current page

Comment: I am calling my observer on product save after